# Socket InputStream returns previous command data [ANDROID/JAVA]

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

In my android application I want to do following things with server

1.Connect
2.Fetch Data
3.Disconnect

I got success in Connecting and fetching data from Server using Socket.

Code for connecting to server :-

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //Read data in the input buffer
        response = br.readLine().toString();

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        throw new CustomException(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        throw new CustomException(response);
    }
```

I checked the response which is correct one :-

```
220 *************************************************************************
```

Code for fetching data :-

```
    try {
        if(socket.isConnected())
        {
            Log.v("TAG","Connected");
        }
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        os.writeBytes("EHLO\r\n");
        os.flush();
        String responseLine = "";
        while (is.available() > 0) {
            responseLine = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
            status = true;
            if (responseLine.contains("\r\n")) {
                Log.v("TAG",""+ responseLine);
                break;
            }
        }
```

In while loop everytime checked response which gives correct value :-

```
250-indition.cc [::ffff:117.195.116.165]
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 CRAM-SHA1 CRAM-SHA256 CRAM-RIPEMD DIGEST-MD5
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 CRAM-SHA1 CRAM-SHA256 CRAM-RIPEMD DIGEST-MD5
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 40960000
250-ETRN
250-XXXXXXXA
250 XXXB
```

But now after doing that when I disconnect to server then it gives response as it is fetching data.
Code for disconnecting :-

```
try {
        if(socket.isConnected())
        {
            Log.v("TAG","Connected");
        }
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("quit\r\n");
        os.flush();
        is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String responseLine = "";
        while (is.available() > 0) {
            responseLine = is.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
        }
```

Instead of getting response of disconnecting from server which will be look like :-

```
221 indition.cc closing connection
```

Connection closed by foreign host.

It gives response of fetching data.I an not closing any InputStream and OutputStream.

Kindly provide solution for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blame your server that it does not send the right date after receiving a quit line.

Comment: Why are you converting the result of `readLine()` to String when it is already a String?